# setGraphicsEventEnv() not supported under Linux?

Tags: linux, r, event-handling, x11, ubuntu-11.10

I'd like to run a script containing an interactive part on a Ubuntu 64 bit machine. Unfortunately it fails throwing the following error:

```
Error in setGraphicsEventEnv(which, as.environment(list(...))) : 
  this graphics device does not support event handling
```

Any hints how I can setup R such that it supports event handling? X11 should be supported according to the documentation.

This examples fails on my machine with the error above:
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/getGraphicsEvent.html

Thanks!
Durin

$ R --version
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Copyright (C) 2011 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License version 2.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

Comment: I don't know if it will work on your system because you have a pretty old version of R (current version is 3.0.1), but this works for me if I specify `X11(type="Xlib")` as hinted at in the comments of the example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X11(type="Xlib") fixed the issue. Thanks!